# Cleaning a CSV string to remove unwanted rows in memory

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV that is semicolon separated, and that uses double quotes as a quote character. I get this CSV from an API, the raw data looks like this :

```
1;"toto@toto.com";"Toto";"Tata"
2;"BAD_DATA"
"BAD_DATA"
3;"alice@alice;com";"Alice";"Dupont"
4;"bob@bob.fr";"Bob";"Morane"
```

The second and third lines are like this because of encoding problems at the source, I cannot change this.

I would like to change the string to this :

```
1;"toto@toto.com";"Toto";"Tata"
3;"alice@alice;com";"Alice";"Dupont"
4;"bob@bob.fr";"Bob";"Morane"
```

So that all the lines with the wrong length are deleted. But since my code will run on a server, I would like if possible to do all of this in memory, without writing to a file on the machine.

As you can see, some of the fields can contain semicolons so I need to protect those with double quotes around them. It adds a little complexity.

So far, I have this :

```py
import csv

myString = f'''1;"toto@toto.com";"Toto";"Tata"
2;"BAD_DATA"
"BAD_DATA"
3;"alice@alice;com";"Alice";"Dupont"
4;"bob@bob.fr";"Bob";"Morane"'''

lines =  myString.splitlines()

reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

for row in reader:
    if len(row) == 4:
        # I don't know what to do here
```

I anybodys knows in what direction I can try to advance, that would be very nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly filters out rows that don't contain exactly 4 columns already. You can use a `csv.writer` to write what passes the filter to an `IO.StringIO` file object so you can get the output as a string with the object's `getvalue` method. However, since the first column of your expected output is unquoted and is the only numeric column, you should configure your writer to use the `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` quoting option, and convert the first column to an integer before passing the columns to the writer's `writerows` method for output:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

myString = f'''1;"toto@toto.com";"Toto";"Tata"
2;"BAD_DATA"
"BAD_DATA"
3;"alice@alice;com";"Alice";"Dupont"
4;"bob@bob.fr";"Bob";"Morane"'''

output = StringIO()
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(myString), delimiter=';')
writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
writer.writerows((int(id), *rest) for id, *rest in reader if len(rest) == 3)
print(output.getvalue())
```

This outputs:

```
1;"toto@toto.com";"Toto";"Tata"
3;"alice@alice;com";"Alice";"Dupont"
4;"bob@bob.fr";"Bob";"Morane"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed ! I had been trying to make `StringIO` work but was not familiar with this library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension and .join method of str,

```
result_str = ''
for row in reader:
    if len(row) == 4:
        result_str += ';'.join(str(x) for x in row) + '\n'

print(result_str.strip())
```

which prints:

```
1;toto@toto.com;Toto;Tata
3;alice@alice;com;Alice;Dupont
4;bob@bob.fr;Bob;Morane
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would not work. As you can see on the second row Alice has a semicolon in her email address so it would be splitted into 2 columns. This is why I need to have quotes around the fields.